# Check out files from Starteam (5.1) but ignore the specified working folder

Tags: starteam

This question is specific to Starteam version 5.1.

How do I export the most recent version of every file in a Starteam project so that the files end up in a directory structure that matches the folder structure in Starteam?

Here’s the catch: many of the Starteam folders have a hardcoded physical path specified as the working folder’s default value instead of just using the relative path.

Here’s an example:

[image: sample]

The working folder for “Custom” is “C:\Projects\Custom”

The working folder for “Training” is “C:\Projects\Custom\Training”

However, the working folder for “Configuration Management” is “d:\TestFiles\CM” so all the files in “Configuration Management” end up on the d: drive.

There are thousands of folders and I don’t know which ones have hardcoded paths.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following actually helped but it was still a manual process:

When looking at a project, show all the files in all of its sub-directories (“File” menu |”All Descendants” will do the trick).  If you sort all the files by the “Path” value you can see all of the output directories and easily find ones that are set to something other than the folder’s default value.